# I want to redirect on particular page after click on submit button

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

[image]I have two submit buttons in contact form 7. I want to set two different redirection link on both buttons after sent mail. How can I set links on different buttons

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() { 

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#down_pc').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.test.com/';
    return false;
});
$('#down_mac').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.test2.com/';
    return false;
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

I have put onclick event but it is redirect without sent mail and without check validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it will help you

```
function action_wpcf7_submit( $instance, $result ) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $( '#down_pc' ).click( function() {
             window.location.href = 'http://www.test.com/';
             return false;
         } );

         $( '#down_mac' ).click( function() {
             window.location.href = 'http://www.test2.com/';
             return false;
         } );
    </script>
<?php }; 

add_action( 'wpcf7_submit', 'action_wpcf7_submit', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I have checked with this but above error is displaying in response. Please check image

Comment: So, there they have mentioned another link which we can use https://contactform7.com/dom-events/